# how to evaluate cosine value by non scientific calculator with at least 12 significant digits

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, calculator

everyone.

I wanna know is there any method to evaluate cosine value by non-scientific calculator with at least 12 significant digits? Recently I have a mathematics exam and teachers can let us bring normal non-scientific calculator, but the math questions have some transdendal functions, so that is there have any way to evaluate it and have to evaluate it with highest accuracy. Thanks a lot.

I try to evaluate it by Taylor expansion but there is a problem with factorial, due to normal non-scientific calculator just have 8-14 digits only, so I can't do it by Taylor expansion.

Is anyone know how to do, just tell me thanks, for example, if I want to evaluate cos(40000) (in radian), write down all the steps, thank you

Comment: If you're being allowed to bring a normal non-scientific calculator that they know isn't capable of evaluating $\operatorname{cos}(x)$ directly, then that suggests the questions are likely to be based on the special ratios/angles. I suggest your time would be better spent learning those (and the trig identities), rather than chasing after a particular algorithm workable on an ordinary calculator. After all, if you were expected to solve it that way, don't you think you'd have been shown how?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you gave a specific example of an exam problem in which you need a 12-digit accuracy (even a 3 or 4 digit accuracy), because I strongly suspect that the problems are intended to be solved without having to do extensive arithmetical calculations.

Comment: Dear calculatorholic, there is something odd in your query, you can't use Taylor expansion you say, since busines calculator just have 8-14 digits only. For sure your model offers some more, but how about those colleagues who can't afford a calculator like yours and they have a model with only 8 digits -- how could the teachers insist to calculate $cos()$ with 12 digits? _At least_ 12 digits.

Comment: ok,  you guys are very curious about it, actually , it's not a exam but something like a competition, a calculator competition, they just offer a normal non scientific calculator and you have to evaluate some values like sin , cosh , log , ln , exp , .... etc, but they don't give you any math formula

Comment: @m-stgt They will offer 14-digits calculator to me

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro it's like a calculator competition , so I don't know how is the problem they give, but all the problems will have transdendal functions like sin , cos , cosh , exp ,log .... etc

Answer (score 0):

One brings the argument into the domain $[0,\pi/2]$ by
integer division through $\pi/2$, using $\cos(\alpha+2\pi)=\cos\alpha$
and $\cos(2\pi-\alpha)=\cos \alpha$ and $\cos(\pi-\alpha)=-\cos\alpha$
and $\cos(\pi/2-\alpha)=\sin\alpha$. What is left is to calculate $\sin\alpha$
for $\alpha$ in the range $[0,\pi/2]$. If there are limits on the absolute
accuracy one uses a Chebyshev expansion of $\sin\alpha$ (coefficients
in https://doi.org/10.2307/2006232 ),
for limits on the relative accuracy a Chebyshev expansion of $(\sin\alpha)/\alpha$ (coefficients in
Example 5.9 in https://arxiv.org/abs/0403344 ).